# SwiftUI AngularGradient smooth transition

Tags: swift, swiftui, gradient

There is a very hard transition on circle. How can I smooth this transition?

**Angular Gradient:**

```
struct DiskSizeInfoView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            Circle()
                .stroke(Color(UIColor.secondarySystemBackground),lineWidth: 30)
            Circle()
                .trim(from: 1 - (1 / (1024 / 1024)), to: 1)
                .stroke(AngularGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.red, Color.green]), center: .center, startAngle: .zero, endAngle: .degrees(360)),style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 30, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
                .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 90))
                .rotation3DEffect(Angle(degrees: 180), axis: (x: 1, y: 0, z: 0))
            
            Text("\(512)")
                .font(.system(size: 30, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
        }
        .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
    }
}
```

**Trim (1024 / 1024):**

[image]

**Trim (1024 / 512):**

[image]

Comment: Maybe `[Color.red, Color.green, Color.red]`